# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append' python error

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a nice and bad list but it keeps giving me this error its something to do with attributes and strings: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
Here's the code

```
print("                    /\ ")
print("                   / o\ ")
print("                  / o o\ ")
print("                 / o o o\ ")
print("                / o o o o\ ")
print("               /__________\ ")
print("                    |_|")

print("press d when your done")

presents = ""



while presents != "d":
  print("")
  time.sleep(0.4)
  present = input("What do you want for Christmas?\n")
  if present == "d":
    print("Your presents are coming in a few days. HO HO HHHHHHHHHHHOOOOOOOOOOOO MEEEEERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRYYYYYYYYYYYY CCCCCCCCCCCCHHHHHHHHHHHHHHRRRRRRRRRRRIIIIIIIIIIISSSSSSSSSTTTTTTTTTTTTMMMMMMMMMAASS!!!!!")
    break


good =  ["Simon", "Anastazja", "Simon", "Shane", "Mihai", "Ben", "Adrea", "Thomas", "Patrick", "Mahmed", "Matis", "Anton", "Nicolas", "Andrei", "Daniel", "Lesia", "Maria"]

bad = ["Conor"]

check = input("I have you been (N)nice or (B)bad this year? ")

if check == "N":
  check.append(good)
  print(good)
elif check == "N":
  check.append(bad)
  print(bad)
```

I can't figure out what's wrong.
Can somebody please help me

Comment: What exactly you expect your code to do?  What is the purpose of your `good` and `bad` arrays?

Answer (score 3):

You have

```
check = input("I have you been (N)nice or (B)bad this year? ")
```

This makes check a string. And then you have `check.append(good)` which is incorrect because check is of type string and strings in python does not have an append. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to put a condition if the person picks N then their names will be put in the nice list If they choose B then their names will be sent to the bad list. (sorry But I forgot to put the input for their names)

Comment: Where are you getting the names from? There is no code to get the name from the user. good and bad are arrays. Please read [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-3-basics/?ref=lbp). This will help you get started

Comment: Here is the new code but still gives me an error:

Comment: sorry I can't because it has to many letters

Comment: Update your question with an EDIT.

Comment: I don't know how to

Comment: somebody edited already

Comment: Sorry I'm just have my first badge

Answer (score 0):

Here is the new code:

````
print("                    /\ ")
print("                   / o\ ")
print("                  / o o\ ")
print("                 / o o o\ ")
print("                / o o o o\ ")
print("               /__________\ ")
print("                    |_|")

print("press d when your done")

presents = ""



while presents != "d":
  print("")
  time.sleep(0.4)
  present = input("What do you want for Christmas?\n")
  if present == "d":
    print("Your presents are coming in a few days. HO HO HHHHHHHHHHHOOOOOOOOOOOO MEEEEERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRYYYYYYYYYYYY CCCCCCCCCCCCHHHHHHHHHHHHHHRRRRRRRRRRRIIIIIIIIIIISSSSSSSSSTTTTTTTTTTTTMMMMMMMMMAASS!!!!!")
    break
  








good =  ["Simon", "Anastazja", "Simon", "Shane", "Mihai", "Ben", "Adrea", "Thomas", "Patrick", "Mahmed", "Matis", "Anton", "Nicolas", "Andrei", "Daniel", "Lesia", "Maria"]

bad = ["Conor"]

check1 = input("I have you been (N)nice or (B)bad this year? ")
check2 = input("What is your name?")

if check1 == "N":
  check2.append(good)
  print(good)
elif check1 == "B":
  check2.append(bad)
  print(bad)```
````

Comment: You are making the same mistake again.. When you call `input()`, and capture the result. That result is a string. Once again, please try to understand basics of Python before you start coding. Your code is backwards. If you are trying to add the name to the list of good or bad, it needs to be `good.append(check2)` or `bad.append(check2)`